# Построение запроса CriteriaBuilder для сравнения списков

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteriabuilder

Как сравнить список из таблицы БД и список из кода программы?
В базе есть профили пользователей Profile с навыками Skills.

```java
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "profile_skills",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Map<Integer, Skill> skills = new TreeMap<>();
```

Нужно найти профили пользователей у которых имеются нужные навыки.
Я сделал запрос, но он выбирает профили у которых есть хотя бы одно совпадение с любым из навыков в списке. Однако мне нужно отобрать только те у которых имеются все навыки указанные в списке (совпадение со всеми элементами списка).

```java
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Profile> cq = cb.createQuery(Profile.class);
    Root<Profile> root  = cq.from(Profile.class);
    MapJoin<Profile, Integer, Skill> skillMapJoin = root.join(Profile_.skills);
    Expression<String> nameSkill = skillMapJoin.get(Skill_.name);

    List<String> skills = Arrays.asList("Java", "JavaScript");

    cq.where(nameSkill.in(skills)).groupBy(root.get(Profile_.id));

    TypedQuery<Profile> q = em.createQuery(cq);
    List<Profile> profiles = q.getResultList();
```

Например:
Profile1.Skills : "Java", "Scala", "Groovy", "JavaScript"
Profile2.Skills : "Java", "Scala", "Groovy"
Profile3.Skills : "Groovy", "JavaScript"

Мой запрос выдаёт результат: Profile1, Profile2, Profile3
А должен быть результат: Profile1

**Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать нужный мне запрос?**
**Как сравнить список из таблицы БД и список из кода программы?**
Можно не только с использованием CriteriaBuilder, но и другие варианты запросов типа sql или jpql.

Comment: Вероятно, Вам необходимо [реляционное деление](https://www.sql.ru/forum/874832/zapros-relyacionnoe-delenie).

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл решение, хотя думаю, что это можно сделать и по другому.

```java
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Profile> cq = cb.createQuery(Profile.class);
    Root<Profile> root  = cq.from(Profile.class);
    MapJoin<Profile, Integer, Skill> skillMapJoin = root.join(Profile_.skills);
    Expression<String> nameSkill = skillMapJoin.get(Skill_.name);

    List<String> skills = Arrays.asList("Java", "JavaScript");
    Integer sizeListValue = skills.size();
    Expression<Long> countSkills = cb.count(exp);

    cq.where(nameSkill.in(skills))
      .groupBy(root.get(Profile_.id))
      .having(cb.equal(countSkills, sizeListValue));

    TypedQuery<Profile> q = em.createQuery(cq);
    List<Profile> profiles = q.getResultList();
```